# Stanford quiz Asymptotic Analysis? Assume again two(positive nondecreasing functions f and g such that f(n) = O(g(n)). Is 2^f(n) = O(2^g(n))? )

Tags: algorithm, math, runtime, asymptotic-complexity

Can somebody please help me work through this problem, and its presented solution?

I can't seem to fully grasp it.

[Question 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVuRA.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question should be in the body of the Question, not in the title, and you should show us what you've worked out so far.

Comment: The correct answer is explained in [the image you inserted in your question](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gTU1k.png). If you have a problem with this explanation (and with the lecture material that preceded this exercise), please describe it in your question.

Answer (score -1):

Let's assume for a moment that it is correct. Now obviously [image] means that [image] for some constant `K` and large `n`.

Now for a counter example. Suppose for some functions [image]; the original bound statement still holds. Then

[image]

But [image], and we know that [image]. So we have disproved the statement [image] by counter-example.

Comment: I was able to follow your answer up until the 4^n = Omega(2^n) >> Omega(2^n). How does Omega(2^n) >> Omega(2^n) ? I apologize if my question contains a very trivial answer, I just cannot see it.

Comment: the last one is O, not omega. O is for less-than-or-equal-to, whereas Omega is greater-than-or-equal-to. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Big_Omega_notation. also I should have used _little_-omega (strict), apologies